# YouTrack Lite How to automatically track time

Tags: youtrack, time-tracking

Is there anyway to track time with just Start/End Button with automatic adding to Spent time field?
Tried Clockify. It doesn't work at Lite version and even in Classical one it just track specific task inside Clockify app without transferring to YouTrack Spent Time Field.

Workflow called workTimer that starts a timer each time issue is moved to 'In progress' state is not an option as we don't use field State.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use YouTrack's default Stopwatch-style work timer (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/Workflow-Standalone-Work-Timer.html). It doesn't use the State field. Instead, it starts the timer when the corresponding Timer field is set to Start. After setting the Timer field to Stop, the timer stops and adjusts the Spent time field accordingly. You can attach the default workflow to your project; after that, the workflow will suggest you to add all required fields automatically.

Please note that work items are not displayed in YouTrack Lite at the moment. However, the nearest major YouTrack release will solve this, bringing time tracking for YouTrack Lite. So for now you can see only the total spent time value of each issue. To see the work items themselves, you'll need to switch to YouTrack Classic.